# Pandas .isin() for list of values in each row of a column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a small problem: I have a column in my DataFrame, which has multiple rows, and in each row it holds either 1 or more values starting with 'M' letter followed by 3 digits. If there is more than 1 value, they are separated by a comma.
I would like to print out a view of the DataFrame, only featuring rows where that 1 column holds values I specify (e.g. I want them to hold any item from list ['M111', 'M222'].
I have started to build my boolean mask in the following way:

```
df[df['Column'].apply(lambda x: x.split(', ').isin(['M111', 'M222']))]
```

In my mind, .apply() with .split() methods in there first convert 'Column' values to lists in each row with 1 or more values in it, and then .isin() method confirms whether or not any of items in list of items in each row are in the list of specified values ['M111', 'M222'].
In practice however, instead of getting a desired view of DataFrame, I get error

```
'TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Kind regards,
Greem

Comment: you are applying isin method on a list( result on x.split()). you apply isin method on a dataframe or a series object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you need:

```
df2 = df[df['Column'].str.contains('|'.join(['M111', 'M222']))]
```

Comment: For dates and times, I had to call `df['Column'].astype(str).str.contains` in order for it to work.

Answer (score 5):

You can only access the `isin()` method with a Pandas object.  But `split()` returns a list.  Wrapping `split()` in a `Series` will work:

```
# sample data
data = {'Column':['M111, M000','M333, M444']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

print(df)
       Column
0  M111, M000
1  M333, M444
```

Now wrap `split()` in a `Series`.
Note that `isin()` will return a list of boolean values, one for each element coming out of `split()`.  You want to know "whether or not **any** of item in list...are in the list of specified values", so add `any()` to your `apply` function.

```
df[df['Column'].apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.split(', ')).isin(['M111', 'M222']).any())]
```

Output:

```
       Column
0  M111, M000
```

As others have pointed out, there are simpler ways to go about achieving your end goal.  But this is how to resolve the specific issue you're encountering with `isin()`.

Comment: I can see how this is a complicated approach, and the str.contains() method makes a quick and easier work of it. But for the sake of satisfying my curiosity, can you please let me know what is the effect of applying lambda x: pd.Series(x.split(', ') to the 'Column' column? The way I read it, it looks like each row in that column will get converted to a Series object with as many rows of its own, as many values were contained in each string separated by commas?